# How can I clear all previous commits from git history?

Tags: git

I have started a new project recently, and I've made a lot of experiments at it's beginning. Now some new people are joining, and I have an idea of wiping the first commits away from git history, because they seem to make no sense and everyone browsing the repo can get confused.

A possible solution is setting up a new repo from scratch, but I would prefer rewriting the history.

What I need is just setting the HEAD commit on master to be the first and only commit in the repo.

Comment: Create a new git repository and throw away the old one? That sounds like the best way to get what you like to do.

Comment: i think you should revisit your preference for blowing away history.  you as the original author may want to reference something down the road.  i'd highly recommend just creating a new repo and keeping your other one to yourself.

Comment: @NG, that would require changing configs on several staging servers

Comment: if they all point to the same remote, you can still move the current repo, git init a bare repo that replaces the current one and then push a single commit to it.  do you not own the remote?

Comment: @NG I own it. I just do not want to change the repo url everywhere

Comment: The answers given are correct. I just wanted to add that you *could* create a tag which points to the old history and even push that one too, just in case you want to keep a reference onto the old history.

Comment: *Why* would you prefer rewriting the history? Deleting and recreating the repo is the simplest and most reliable way to do what you want (consider grabbing a copy of the repo first). `rm -rf .git; git init; git add .; git commit -m "..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `git rebase` you might be interessted in [Git - squash entire branch - one line squash command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27697274/974186).

If you have a history with a lot of commits, `git rebease` might take a long time. In this case you can make a shallow clone

```
git clone --depth 1 <REPO_URL>
```

than do a

```
git commit --amend
```

in order to create an independent commit that contains the latest changes
and than do a forced push

```
git push -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Squash all unwanted commit in your local repository, and then push them into remote repository with the `--force` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really sure about what you are doing you can do an interactive rebase onto your first commit:

```
git rebase --interactive --root
```

and fixup every single commit.
But at least I would recommend to checkout another branch before:

```
git checkout -b rebase
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new root branch without any parent commit using

```
git checkout --orphan new-master
```

and commit the repository state to that new branch using

```
git add .
git commit
```

and push it to the server using

```
git push --force origin new-master:master
```

This will make the old history unaccessible on the server, so use it with care.