# How to wipe history from SourceTree for a complete noob?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, unreal-blueprint

I am a complete coding and programming noob. I'm currently doing a project in Unreal Engine 4 using just Blueprints. I'm becoming more and more interested in coding but as of now, assume I know close to nothing.

I'm using Sourcetree together with Bitbucket to back things up, but I recently had to change around the folder structure in UE4, which means SourceTree now wants to upload every single thing as a new item, which would bring me above the 2GB limit.

I don't really need to keep any of the previous commits at this stage, so is there a way to basically just wipe them all and start over with this new folder structure as a base? Or alternatively start a new project in Sourcetree?

Comment: Are you using git or mercurial for source control?

Comment: I am using git.

Answer (score 0):

if you really noob, my suggestion is to download the latest update on your project from your git repository .

Then make new repository and push it to be like an initial one. this is the easiest and noobest way.

For more advanced solution:
[How can I clear all previous commits from git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027468/how-can-i-clear-all-previous-commits-from-git-history)